# Images missing from Entries, but still on server

Tags: entries, assets, database

Have a bit of an issue.

Recently, a site I work had its asset index rebuilt upon finishing for some reason all images associated to entries are now no longer attached. They are still on the server and in the database.

How would one go about linking these back-up as I don't fancy going through every entry to reassociate the image manually.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You sure the index successfully completed and didn't error at some point?

Comment: If this did happen. Should i just re run it?

Comment: Nope rerunning the asset index didn't work.
Any ideas folks?

Comment: If an answer provides a solution to your problem it's good etiquette, and good manners, to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same problem. All images in my entries are lost after clearing the cache :-O

Answer (score 1):

Clear the caches after updating the assets index, asset indexing data at the very least, though I'd normally clear everything to be sure.

[image]